# Ampscript "lookup" don't work for synchronized data extension "Case_Salesforce"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to extract data from synchronized data extension "Case_Salesforce" to show on an email.
Is it possible to do this? I am using lookup function to achieve.
I can get synchronized data extension "Contact_Salesforce" ,but cannot get data out of "Case_Salesforce".
Does Anyone know what the differnce is between them?

```
%%[<br>
var @lookupvalue,@CaseId,@Subject,@ContactEmail,@Status<br>
set @lookupvalue = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")<br>
set @CaseId = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Id","Id",@lookupvalue)<br>
set @Subject = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Subject","Id",@lookupvalue)<br>
set @ContactEmail = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","ContactEmail","Id",@lookupvalue)<br>
set @Status = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Status","Id",@lookupvalue)<br>
]%%<p>
Case Detail<br>
CaseID:%%=v(@CaseId)=%%<br>
Subject:%%=v(@Subject)=%%<br>
Status:%%=v(@Status)=%%<br>
</p>
```

Comment: AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") delete the " that it becomes AttributeValue(_subscriberkey)

Comment: I revised this script as you commented but didn't work.

Comment: Is the column where your subscriberkey is located really named "id" in all dataextensions? Is it really subscriberkey or is it subscriberid? Furthermore this makes no sense `set @CaseId = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Id","Id",@lookupvalue)` you lookup the "ID" value and search with ID you insert there. That makes no sense

Comment: One sidenote: It makes no sense to do 4 Lookups against the same dataextension when you could use LookUpRows oder LookUpOrderedRows functions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Though I wondered that the error is difference between "Contact_Salesforce" and “Case_Salesforce”,can ampscript I modify well extract data from synchronized data extension “Case_Salesforce” ?

Comment: the column named "id" is connected subscriberkey and synced the field of "CaseId" in SF.
And this is the field of one data extension.

Answer (score 1):

- Please make sure you have these additional fields added to your SYNCED object.
  [image]

  - Then make sure you are searching based on "ContactID" and NOT "Id"

```
%%[
var @lookupvalue,@CaseId,@Subject,@ContactEmail,@Status
set @lookupvalue = "0030o00002dgaRDAAY"
set @CaseId = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Id","ContactId",@lookupvalue)
set @Subject = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Subject","ContactId",@lookupvalue)
set @ContactEmail = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","ContactEmail","ContactId",@lookupvalue)
set @Status = Lookup("Case_Salesforce","Status","ContactId",@lookupvalue)
]%%

Case Detail
CaseID:%%=v(@CaseId)=%% <br/>
Subject:%%=v(@Subject)=%% <br/>
Status:%%=v(@Status)=%% <br/>
```

- I have hardcoded the subkey for testing. And it worked for me!
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I confirmed that your script works in my instance as expected. 
Would you tell me what I should use to instead of hard-code? "subkey"? or "subid"?

Comment: @Masashi - subid is an internal ID of SFMC. The Contact ID from SC is to be referenced as subkey

Comment: @Kumar  Can't any fields except Contact ID from SF referenced as subkey?

Comment: As per my knowledge it's always better only to use either ContactId  or. LeadId as SubKey.... Preferably 18digitId if u have.. else u can go with regular 15 digit IDs